# moveRowAtIndexPath using CoreData in Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, tableview, reorderlist

After reading more than 10 posts written in Obj-C & Swift.
I still don't figure out how to reorder the rows in my list using CoreData.

Since I know how to add a new object and how to delete one I tried to merge both together and my `moveRowAtIndexPath` method became

```
let prefToMove = mainVC.user.prefs[fromIndexPath.row] as! Pref

var prefs = mainVC.user.prefs.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet
prefs.addObject(prefToMove)

mainVC.user.prefs = prefs.copy() as! NSOrderedSet

// managed object context saving
var error: NSError?
do {
  try managedContext!.save()
} catch let error1 as NSError {
  error = error1
  print("Could not save: \(error)")
}
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths([toIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)

prefs = mainVC.user.prefs.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet
prefs.removeObjectAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row)
mainVC.user.prefs = prefs.copy() as! NSOrderedSet

managedContext.deleteObject(prefToMove)

// managed object context saving
do {
  try managedContext.save()
} catch let error1 as NSError {
  error = error1
  print("Could not save: \(error)")
}

// Delete the row from the data source
tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([fromIndexPath], withRowAnimation: .None)

tableView.reloadData()
```

However, it does not work. The delete part works but the insertion fails.
Someone can give me any help?

Comment: Just a remark: A larger audience will understand your code if you use english names for variables, methods etc.

Comment: @MartinR modified as requested. Thanks for the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

You're not really deleting or inserting anything when you move rows around. Whatever your data set is, try `exchangeObjectAtIndex`

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, moveRowAtIndexPath fromIndexPath: NSIndexPath, toIndexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    let orderedSet: NSMutableOrderedSet = (routineToReorder?.mutableOrderedSetValueForKey("yourKeyValue"))!

    orderedSet.exchangeObjectAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row, withObjectAtIndex: toIndexPath.row)

    saveManagedObjectContext() // I have a standalone method for this that I call from several places
}
```

**Update**

Here's what `saveManagedObjectContext()` looks like:

```
func saveManagedObjectContext() {
    if self.managedObjectContext.hasChanges {
        do {
            try managedObjectContext.save()
        } catch {
            // Replace this implementation with code to handle the error appropriately.
            // abort() causes the application to generate a crash log and terminate. You should not use this function in a shipping application, although it may be useful during development.
            let nserror = error as NSError
            NSLog("Unresolved error \(nserror), \(nserror.userInfo)")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: your code is not so easy to understand, perhaps for pros only. I cannot understand what I should put as 'routineToReorder'

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out thanks to @AdrianB because I didn't know the method `orderedSet.exchangeObjectAtIndex`

In my case the following implementation works

```
let preferiti = calcoloVC.utenteCorrente.preferiti.mutableCopy() as! NSMutableOrderedSet
preferiti.exchangeObjectAtIndex(fromIndexPath.row, withObjectAtIndex: toIndexPath.row)
calcoloVC.utenteCorrente.preferiti = preferiti.copy() as! NSOrderedSet

var error: NSError?
do {
  try managedContext.save()
} catch let error1 as NSError {
  error = error1
  print("Could not save: \(error)")
}
```

Now I need to figure out where to write the saveManagedObjectContext without rewriting it every time.

Comment: Added code for saving `managedObjectContext`. See update to my answer.

Comment: @AdrianB Thanks. Where did you put that? CoreDataStack.swift?

Comment: Stuck it in the class.